FLASK API Problem for containerlab command for docker
There is command that I use for docker environment:
containerlab deploy -t topology.yaml

This command creates network topology lab environment with containers. When  I run this command, it gives some outputs then creates lab as below:
root@ubuntu:~/Arista/AristaDCEVPNVXLAN# containerlab  deploy -t aristadcevpnvxlan.yaml 
INFO[0000] Containerlab v0.54.2 started                 
INFO[0000] Parsing & checking topology file: aristadcevpnvxlan.yaml 
INFO[0000] Creating docker network: Name="clab", IPv4Subnet="172.23.0.0/26", IPv6Subnet="", MTU=1500 
INFO[0000] Creating lab directory: /root/Arista/AristaDCEVPNVXLAN/clab-1999 
INFO[0000] Creating container: "leaf4"                  
INFO[0000] Creating container: "host2"                  
INFO[0000] Creating container: "spine1"                 
INFO[0000] Creating container: "leaf3"                  
INFO[0002] Running postdeploy actions for Arista cEOS 'host2' node 
INFO[0002] Created link: spine1:eth4 <--> leaf3:eth2    
INFO[0002] Created link: spine1:eth5 <--> leaf4:eth2    
INFO[0002] Running postdeploy actions for Arista cEOS 'spine1' node 
INFO[0002] Created link: leaf3:eth1 <--> leaf4:eth1     
INFO[0002] Created link: leaf3:eth4 <--> host2:eth1     
INFO[0002] Running postdeploy actions for Arista cEOS 'leaf3' node 
INFO[0002] Created link: leaf3:eth6 <--> leaf4:eth6     
INFO[0002] Created link: leaf4:eth4 <--> host2:eth2     
INFO[0002] Running postdeploy actions for Arista cEOS 'leaf4' node 

My purpose is    to use flask to gives an output from Apache web server. I installed that environment. My flask  myapp.py file as below:
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def run_containerlab():
    command = "containerlab deploy -t Arista/AristaDCEVPNVXLAN/aristadcevpnvxlan.yaml"
    result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
    output = result.stdout
    return jsonify({"output": output})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("0.0.0.0")

When I test from http://172.22.111.11. I am getting below error:
{
output: "time="2024-05-03T20:32:17Z" level=error msg="stat /var/www/.config: no such file or directory"
"
}

Do you have any clue why I am getting this  response?
When I create .config file under /var/wwww, then I am getting another error such that there is no
var/wwww/.config/containers/storage.conf .
I am also creating this , and another error.
If I run this containerlab command in bash, it is working properly
